# StringFormat is ignored

Tags: wpf, binding, string-literals, string-formatting

This is my binding (shortened, Command-Property is also bound)

```
<MenuItem Header="Key" CommandParameter="{Binding StringFormat='Key: {0}', Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
```

The Tag-Property of ContectMenu's PlacementTarget is a String like

```
"Short.Plural"
```

What i expect to receive in the Command-Handler is:

```
Key: Short.Plural
```

But what i acutally receive is:

```
Short.Plural
```

Comment: are you sending this value to the command Parameter?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Label does not use StringFormat but ContentStringFormat. Use it this way:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="Base Text"/>
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=textBlock}" ContentStringFormat="FORMATTED {0}"/>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Also for a MenuItem to format the Header it's HeaderStringFormat

Answer (score 24):

I'm astounded, but my tests just show that `StringFormat` only applies if the target d-prop is of type `String`. I've never noticed this before, nor heard it mentioned. I don't have more time to look into it right now, but this seems ridiculous.

Seriously, this works:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="Base Text"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=FORMATTED {0}, Path=Text, ElementName=textBlock}"/>
```

This does not:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="Base Text"/>
<Label Content="{Binding StringFormat=FORMATTED {0}, Path=Text, ElementName=textBlock}"/>
```

Since `Label.Content` is not a `String`.

Comment: But commandparameter doesn't seem to recognize the stringformat or at least it doesn't know how to use it, so it only returns the value that is in the binding not the result of the stringformat.

Answer (score 1):

use Binding Converter:

```
public class CommandParamConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return string.Format("Key {0}", value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add it to Windows\UserControl resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CommandParamConverter x:Key="commandParamConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Refer it in Menu CommandParameter binding:

```
<MenuItem Header="Key" CommandParameter="{Binding Converter={StaticResource commandParamConverter}, Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the only soloution right now... I'm going to use a converter, but with a ConverterParameter => "StringConcatenationConverter"

Comment: @tabina 's answer is better suited for this as it not only removes the requirement for an extra converter but also has the benefit of applying localization easier